# Is it possible to send Python command over ssh?

Tags: python, ssh, cmd

I'm using double ssh connection to perform some operations in remote device. To do this manually I usually need to perform in cmd:

```
ssh username1@hostname1
```

In this connection I perform

```
ssh saved-connection
```

And then I can do something like

```
python -c "print('test')"
```

So far I'm able to run any commands on that device using single command. Example:

```
ssh username1@hostname1 ssh saved-connection pwd
```

But is possible to run from Python code (using any kind of library or just by sending command) some kind of Python command that will be executed on remote device?
Tried following but doesn't work:

```
ssh username1@hostname1 ssh saved-connection python -c "print('test')"
ssh username1@hostname1 ssh saved-connection "python -c "print('test')""
ssh username1@hostname1 ssh saved-connection "python -c \"print('test')\""
```

NOTE: I do not have permissions to save Python script on remote so Python command should be sent directly with ssh command

UPDATE #1:
Operation systems:

- `Main` - can be any of OSs. The goal is Jenkins on Linux but for development I'm using Windows 10 x64
- `username1@hostname1` - Kernel: Linux 5.4.64; OS: NixOS 20.03 (Markhor)
- `saved-connection` - Kernel: Linux 4.9.11; OS:  Linux 2.5.1 (sumo)

Comment: Instead of the double `ssh`, have you considered setting up a tunnel?

Comment: What are the operating systems and shells on all involved hosts? This is going to involve an absurd amount of quoting (which I am too lazy to figure out for you, but anyone who tries will have to know what OS:es and shells they're up against).  And I agree with @FlyingTeller; a tunnel might save you a few grey hairs. Also check out the -J option to ssh.

Comment: @ture-pålsson I am not strong at ssh but the thing is that I'm allowed only to use this ssh connection but not to modify it but as I understand I'm not able to set up a tunnel without modifying any of hosts. And will add OS info to description